# Regular expression to replace whole line if it contains a particular word

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I have a word document, it contains some confidential information like it has NIC:343434343.
I need a regular expression which will do the following thing.

if it finds NIC on a line it should replace the whole line with specified text.

Answer (score 10):

Since by default the dot does not match NewLine, you can simply use

```
.*NIC.*
```

to find lines containing "NIC". You'd use this expression like

```
string result = Regex.Replace(originalString, ".*NIC.*", "replacement string");
```

You can see it at work at [ideone.com](http://ideone.com/QrANa).

Comment: That would match the entire slab of text, not just the line. :o

Comment: @Issun: Why would it? `.` does not match `\n` unless RegexOptions.Singleline is specified.

Comment: Sorry about that, I see what you mean.

Comment: It gives this error "The match includes one or more special or break characters and cannot be replaced"

Comment: @Abdul: I've never seen that error. Can you add some example text to your question that gives that error when using the Regex on it?

Comment: it was giving me error but when I changed the code to this new Regex("[.]*NIC[.]*",RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Multiline) then error gone, and it replaces the word NIC with with the text specified. But what I am trying to do is that if the word NIC is found in any line then this whole line should be replaced with the text I will specify.

Comment: @Abdul: `[.]` represent exactly a dot, while in regex, the `.` stands for every character except newline. Your modified regex replaces "NIC" surrounded by any number of dots. Again, please add example input to your question.

Comment: example Input: NIC: 34324324324324324 we need to replace this whole line with blank space or with some other string.

Comment: @Abdul: That error you're getting is not from the Regex, but from Aspose.Words. See e.g.: http://www.aspose.com/community/forums/thread/36872/the-match-includes-one-or-more-special-or-break-characters-and-cannot-be-replaced.aspx

Answer (score 8):

Use the start and end-of-line markers:

```
^.*NIC.*$
```

`^` matches the start of line and `$` matches the end of line. This will cause the entire line to be matched, if it contains "NIC" at least once.

Comment: `^` and `$` match only the beginning and end of the entire string, unless RegexOptions.Multiline is specified.

Answer (score 3):

Use this regex: `(?m-i)^.*?NIC.*$`. It enables multiline option and disables ignore case option.